# how to add a folder in setup.py to package_data?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I don't know how to add `src` folder to `package_data` if I call `python setup.py sdist` command then go to  distfolder and open `tar.gz` then there is no `src` folder.

Here is the content of my `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import codecs
import os

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

with codecs.open(os.path.join(here, "README.md"), encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = "\n" + fh.read()

VERSION = '0.0.1'
DESCRIPTION = 'Generating and modyfing inages'
LONG_DESCRIPTION = 'A package that allows generate images with numbers, letters and modify the inages'

package_data={
    "folder": ['imgen'],
},

# Setting up
setup(
    name="pyimggen",
    version=VERSION,
    author="Lemskyy (olek-program)",
    author_email="XXXX@gmail.com",
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    long_description=long_description,
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['pypng'],
    keywords=['python', 'image', 'py', 'png', 'library'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 1 - Planning",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Operating System :: Unix",
        "Operating System :: MacOS :: MacOS X",
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
    ]
)
```

Comment: I think you should edit your question to show the relevant parts of the project's directory structure. I also recommend you follow [this (canonical) tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), in which you can select *setuptools* as build back-end. This instructs you to use `pyproject.toml` for the packaging metadata (instead of your `setup.py`) which is the most modern way of packaging Python projects. -- Alternatively you can look at [this page from *setuptools* doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html).